# next.js 404 and 500 pages are not working on windows server

Tags: node.js, next.js, windows-server-2019, iisnode

i launched a next.js e-commerce project on a windows server
i created a server.js and web.config files inside the root directory of the next app
the content of the files is based on what i found about launching next app on windows server on the internet.

server.js

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === "/a") {
      app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
    } else if (pathname === "/b") {
      app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

in development mode 404.tsx and 500.tsx pages are working.
in production mode, when deploying the project on the windows server

when you navigate to the page that doesn't exist
custom 404.tsx page not displayed and the default page 404 page of windows server is showing up

what should i add to the web.config ?

i added some rules to the web.config but it didn't work